# Changing water levels in a rectangular water tank - inkscape

Tags: inkscape

I am creating a rectangular reservoir and need water levels to be able to change. When I move the water, the objects become distorted and slanted (I have added pictures for reference). This issue is not present when using an isometric view, but I have to use this side angle and can not figure out how to keep the water angle level. Is there a way to solve this and keep the reservoir at the current angle?

[image: water somewhat level]
[image: water is very slanted here]

Answer (score 3):

You are just squishing the shape by distorting it.  Instead, select and move the nodes of the shapes you made.

If you construct this using a transparent blue shape, and a parallelogram the same as the top of the tank, then you could select both pieces with the Edit Paths by Nodes tool <kbd>N</kbd>, then use the tool to click and drag to select the nodes you want to move. Then you would be able move them up or down using the arrow keys. Alternatively you can also hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> as you click and drag to constrain the movement vertically.

Here's an example

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way I can lock those bottom nodes in place? The fill level is going to be automated so I need a way to keep those nodes from being selected or moving.

Comment: @user162616 No. Just don't select them. This works by only selecting the nodes you want to move. There's no way to lock nodes of an object in Inskcape. You can lock an object, but then you can't select it.

Comment: @user162616 If by automation you mean animate it, then you may have to rethink this. Perhaps use a mask?  Sorry, animation isn't my area of expertise.